# Uninstall application on remote computer silently

Tags: c#, wmi, uninstallation

I am developing a C# program to remotely uninstall an application. It works fine but the problem is that it does not list all of the installed products on a particular selected computer.

The code for listing the installed product using WMI is :

```
void ListAllProducts()
{
    try
    {
        ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();
        connection.Username = Connect.UserName;
        connection.Password = Connect.Password;
        connection.Authority = "ntlmdomain:MSHOME";

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\"+ Connect.MachineName +"\\root\\CIMV2", connection);
        scope.Connect();

        ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product");

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            listBox4.Items.Add(queryObj["Name"].ToString());
            listBox2.Items.Add (queryObj["Name"].ToString ());
            listBox1.Items.Add(queryObj["IdentifyingNumber"].ToString());
            listBox3.Items.Add(queryObj["Version"].ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (ManagementException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

The code for uninstalling all product is :

```
void UninstallProduct()
{
    try
    {
        ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();
        connection.Username = Connect.UserName;
        connection.Password = Connect.Password;
        connection.Authority = "ntlmdomain:MSHOME";

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\"+Connect.MachineName +"\\root\\CIMV2", connection);
        scope.Connect();

        ManagementObject classInstance = new ManagementObject(scope, new ManagementPath ("Win32_Product.IdentifyingNumber='"+listBox1.Text +"',Name='"+listBox2.Text+"',Version='"+ listBox3.Text+"'"),null);

        // no method in-parameters to define

        // Execute the method and obtain the return values.
        ManagementBaseObject outParams = 
            classInstance.InvokeMethod("Uninstall", null, null);

        // List outParams
       MessageBox.Show ("Uninstallation Starts");
    }
    catch(ManagementException err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while trying to execute the WMI method: " + err.Message);
    }
}
```

Please help me out to list all the products installed on the selected machine and to uninstall it without the consent of the user of that selected machine.

Comment: I need you to read that question back to yourself, and think for a minute whether there's likely to be an API that will do this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question relates to knowing which applications are installed on a remote machine.  Once you know that, you can use your code to uninstall them.  With that being the case, here is a link to an article on how to list all of the applications (with their uninstall information) on a remote computer:

http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2010/12/c-check-if-programapplication-is.html

Answer (score 1):

The WMI [`Win32_Product`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378.aspx) only represents products that are installed by Windows Installer. To get a list of all installed products, you need to enumerate the subkeys of the `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` registry key. To do this remotely, you can use the WMI registry class [`StdRegProv`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393664.aspx) class. TechNet includes sample scripts that show how this can be done, and which you can adapt to your particular needs:

[How do I list all the installed applications on a given machine?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692772.aspx#EBAA)
[List Installed Software](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/28946a87-b306-41e2-a84d-2a1915fd1074/)